# How to use UMLFS?

Tags: fuse

I'm trying to mount what is inside UML session as FUSE filesystem on host.

There's "uml_mount" program which looks like a thing for this purpose, but it fails.

What is UMLFS (I haven't found any documentation at all) and how to mount it?

`uml_mount` mounts FUSE filesystem and starts `uml_mconsole <umid> umlfs <file descriptor>` which tries to send this file descriptor to UML kernel (to deal with further FUSE things), but sending fails. Also I haven't found any signs of FUSE inside a kernel.

Do I need some special patch for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify mountlo-0.6 for the task. At least I can now mount NFS over FUSE using this approach.